# uploaded files by php owned by apache cannot be moved from /tmp

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am using `Apache/2.0.52` (Red Hat) & `php4` to upload files via browser from local computer. The files arrive in `/tmp` looking like this:

```
-rw-------  1 apache apache  18668 Jun 27 02:56 phpi8g4LS
```

I try to use `move_uploaded_file(/tmp/phpi8g4LS, "/var/www/html/images/phpi8g4LS")` and the `/tmp` file cannot be moved.

ERROR:

```
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpYYMatI' to '/var/www/html/images/$NewImageName
```

---

YET, if I write it back to `/tmp/` it works fine.

e.g.

```
if (file_exists($xyz)) 
{

    echo "The file $xyz exists"; //the file $xyz does indeed exist
    move_uploaded_file($xyz,"/tmp/$xyz"); //success!!
    move_uploaded_file($xyz,"/var/www/html/images/$xyz"); //No good!!

} else {

    echo "The file does not exist!";
}
```

I can eliminate permissions as a problem, all the directories I am trying to write to are owned by apache or (gasp!) `0777`. I do this routinely on other linux flavored apache servers with no problems...what is going on here? I've been banging my head on for days! Please help!!

Comment: Where's the `move_uploaded_file` running? In a web request managed by Apache? Or are you trying to do it via the CLI?

Comment: Selinux enabled and blocking the file move?

Comment: I, uh, missed that you're apparently using PHP **FOUR**. PHP 4 was end-of-lifed [a **decade** ago](http://php.net/eol.php) and is beyond unsafe to run. Time to rewrite this code (and probably replace the entire server).

Comment: Apache is managing the web request...Selinux is enabled and blocking, thank you for that suggestion, Mikko. Will mess with that...

Comment: selinux was indeed enabled and blocking move_uploaded_file. Excellent suggestion, Mikko. Thanks to everyone for helping me out!!

Comment: Anyone else who runs into this, the selinux config file is in either /etc/sysconfig/selinux or /etc/selinux/config:                                                           
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled                                                                    
/usr/sbin/setenforce 0

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the Safemode flag turned on in PHP and it is blocking your access. Turn it off in php.ini and try again.

Comment: I was gonna go "lol no that's been gone for ages" but I re-read the question and it says PHP **FOUR**. Hoooooly crap.

Comment: Yeah...I know :-(

Comment: @John R Danison did it work? (safemode off)